# No user-context-has FOSHttpCacheBundle + Varnish

Tags: symfony, caching, varnish

I'm french, so sorry for my English.

My config:
Varnish on port 80
Apache2 on port 8080
Symfony: 2.5.9

I can not have the X-User-Context-Hash my response headers. Can you help me or point me because then I block.

config.vcl:

the same here: http://foshttpcache.readthedocs.org/en/latest/varnish-configuration.html#varnish-user-context except I changed "/user_context_hash.php" by "/ user-context- hash "

```
sub vcl_recv {

    # Prevent tampering attacks on the hash mechanism
    if (req.restarts == 0
        && (req.http.accept ~ "application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash"
            || req.http.x-user-context-hash
        )
    ) {
        return (synth(400));
    }

    # Lookup the context hash if there are credentials on the request
    # Only do this for cacheable requests. Returning a hash lookup discards the request body.
    # https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/652
    if (req.restarts == 0
        && (req.http.cookie || req.http.authorization)
        && (req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD")
    ) {
        # Backup accept header, if set
        if (req.http.accept) {
            set req.http.x-fos-original-accept = req.http.accept;
        }
        set req.http.accept = "application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash";

        # Backup original URL
        set req.http.x-fos-original-url = req.url;
        set req.url = "/user-context-hash";

        # Force the lookup, the backend must tell not to cache or vary on all
        # headers that are used to build the hash.
        return (hash);
    }

    # Rebuild the original request which now has the hash.
    if (req.restarts > 0
        && req.http.accept == "application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash"
    ) {
        set req.url = req.http.x-fos-original-url;
        unset req.http.x-fos-original-url;
        if (req.http.x-fos-original-accept) {
            set req.http.accept = req.http.x-fos-original-accept;
            unset req.http.x-fos-original-accept;
        } else {
            # If accept header was not set in original request, remove the header here.
            unset req.http.accept;
        }

        # Force the lookup, the backend must tell not to cache or vary on the
        # user hash to properly separate cached data.

        return (hash);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.http.accept ~ "application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash"
        && beresp.status >= 500
    ) {
        return (abandon);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # On receiving the hash response, copy the hash header to the original
    # request and restart.
    if (req.restarts == 0
        && resp.http.content-type ~ "application/vnd.fos.user-context-hash"
    ) {
        set req.http.x-user-context-hash = resp.http.x-user-context-hash;

        return (restart);
    }

    # If we get here, this is a real response that gets sent to the client.

    # Remove the vary on context user hash, this is nothing public. Keep all
    # other vary headers.
    set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "(?i),? *x-user-context-hash *", "");
    set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "^, *", "");
    if (resp.http.Vary == "") {
        unset resp.http.Vary;
    }

    # Sanity check to prevent ever exposing the hash to a client.
    unset resp.http.x-user-context-hash;
}
```

config_cache.yml

```
fos_http_cache:
    user_context:
        enabled: true
        role_provider: true
    cache_control:
        defaults:
            overwrite: true
        rules:
            -
                match:
                    path: ^/
                headers:
                    overwrite: true
                    cache_control:
                        public: true
                        max_age: 60000
                        s_maxage: 56000
                    last_modified: "-1 hour"
                    vary: [Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language]
```

routing_cache.yml :

```
user_context_hash:
    path: /user-context-hash
```

app_dev.php :

```
/*require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';*/
/*$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);*/
```

composer.json:

```
"friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle": "1.2.0"
```

Réponse headers:

```
headers 
Date: Mon, 26 Jan 2015 20:11:48 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.35-0+deb7u2
Cache-Control: max-age=60000, public, s-maxage=56000 
X-Cache-Debug: 1
Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Jan 2015 19:11:48 GMT 
x-url: /
x-host: datav1.XXX.com
X-Varnish: 229440 229433
Age: 84 
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4 
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

THX !

Answer (score 0):

Varnish makes several sub-requests internally (called "restarts") to deal with `x-user-context-hash` feature provided by the bundle.

As you can see in the last line in `vcl_deliver` you unset that header, so it won't be exposed among response headers. You can comment out that line while doing development, though it is not recommended to do on production.